# How can I multiply every item in array using lambda?

Tags: ruby

I want to multiply every item in this array:

```
arr = [7, 2]
```

to receive:

```
[14, 4]
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
la = lambda {|item| item * 2}
arr = la.(arr)
p arr
```

But I received:

```
[7, 2, 7, 2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
la = ->e{e * 2}
arr.map!(&la)
```

But this is overkill. Normally, you would do:

```
arr.map!{|e| e * 2}
```

Comment: Educational, as usual! Readers: you probably know that `map!(&:to_s)` converts every element of the receiver to a string. `&`'s role is to convert the symbol `:to_s` to an instance of `Proc` and then `call` the proc, which is equivalent to invoking the method `to_s`. If, however, `&` is followed by a `Proc` (rather than a symbol), as here, it only performs the second step: `call`ing the proc.

Answer (score 0):

You should do that with `map`:

```
2.2.1 :001 > [7, 2].map { |x| x*2 } 
# => [14, 4]
```

You can embed that into a lambda and call it as follows:

```
2.2.1 :002 > mult = ->(a) { a.map { |x| x*2 } }
2.2.1 :006 > mult.call [7,2]
# => [14, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your array to the lambda, so it is multiplying the entire array by 2.

You will want to iterate over each item in the array

```
arr.map{ |a| la.call(a) }
```